# Responsive font size in Android

Tags: android, responsive-design

We can make positioning of widgets 'responsive' by using bias/weight etc, but how do we make the font sizes responsive? By 'responsive' I mean the font size that changes according to size of device - i.e for large device the font size will be large, and for small device the font size will be small.

I tried using the library for ssp/sdp, but that didn't solve the issue.
Another suggested way is to create different font sizes in dimens.xml for different device size, and use them, but that would require calculating the different font sizes for the fonts used in the entire app.
Is there any other way?

Comment: "size that changes according to size of device " - how is that different from `dp` or `sp`? Those units are already density (size) aware.

Comment: Aren't 'density' and 'size' different things? 2 devices with same size can have different densities.

Comment: Density (dots per inch) is  how many pixels are there in a certain area. Size is the physical space available to display the UI.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying to design for size (and ignoring density).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library for font size :

```
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
```